# Why does soap make water feel colder?

Tags: thermodynamics

Whenever I wash my hands I feel like the water gets colder after I use soap. As an experiment, I soaped up just one hand and washed them both under the same water, and the soapy hand felt colder. Is this all in my head or is there a physical explanation?

Comment: Does it feel colder when your hands are under water? Or _after_ you washed them and before you dried them?

Comment: And are you using bar soap or liquid soap, and if liquid what temperature is the soap at compared with the water?

Comment: @JonCuster That's the crucial point. Only if dissolving soap (of whatever kind) is *endothermic* would the OP's observation make sense, unless the soap was significantly colder than the water. AFAIK dissolving soap is not endothermic.

Comment: "Feel" is not objective.  The question is whether your skin temperature is *measured* as lower or higher or the same.

Comment: @Gert - and additives like aloe seem (to me) to make a layer on your skin which may keep the water away for a while even as you wash.

Comment: @JonCuster That film would be to thin to have any insulating effect, IMO...

Comment: I suspect that, to the extent that this sensation is real, the soap causes the water to more readily wet the skin, getting the cold water infinitesimally closer to the heat sensing nerves in your skin.

Comment: @StephenG Not really, when the question specifically refers to how the water feels.

Comment: @GuillermoBCN I don't know if you are saying that you agree it's not objective or claiming we can measure a personal feeling/impression in an objective way in *physics*.

Comment: @StephenG I am saying that the question is not whether the tempterature is actually higher, but in fact why the (necessary) subjective feeling arises. That was the OP’s question.

Comment: @GuillermoBCN From my point of view how a subjective feeling arises is not physics.  Unfortunately human observations relying on personal evaluation are not objective and can conflict between different people experiencing what should be the same thing.  In particular there is an unconscious tendancy for all of us to try and find evidence proving our own initial evaluations.  This is why we rely on objectivity and peer review combined with reproducibility of experiments in physics.

Comment: @StephenG Just a simple example: a common question is ‘why do metals feel colder than other materials on a cold day (or warmer on hot days)’?. This question relies on subjective sensations just as much as the question we are discussing about here. The typical answer involves an explanation about the distinct conductivities of different materials and how those explain the referred sensations. I think this is the type of answer that was expected by the OP.

Comment: @GuillermoBCN Your example is simpler to test and can be made objective in that way.  The OPs question does not (IMO) fall into that category.  There seems no consensus in comments that this is even what everyone (or even most people) experiences.  It could anything from just the OP's possibly fasle opinion, the composition of the soap, something in the water, a combination, of those, the water becoming colder or hotter temporarily for some other reason.  Too many unknowns and no reliable repeatable observation.  The OP was asked for clarifications but did not provide them.